# Redirect user to someone else's home folder - SFTP Filzilla connection

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sftp

Created an SFTP server with chrooted users. Upon login using FileZilla users can only see their incoming/outgoing folders, basically they are jailed inside their home folders.
Now a special user **"spcl.usr"** used by an application) needs to have access to another chrooted user's incoming and outgoing to be set as follow:

The **"spcl.usr"** should have the following permissions on another chrooted home folder:
incoming ---> read only
outgoing ---> read, write and execute

Is there a way to do this without compromising the permissions to other chrooted users?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option could be assign the groups for each jailed ftp users and add to the unified supervisor `spclr.usr` account with the linux
`usermod` command.

With that assigned group rights, it could have read over jailed chroot directories, ie.

```
usermod -a -G groupSftp1,groupSftp2 spcl.usr
```

Answer (score 0):

What OS is the server on?

If it's linux, bind mounting the other user's home dir in your spcl.usr's home dir might work.